# Login to view the Images in the Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a mvc project my url is `hostname/xxxx` and i have folder name called `xxxx` .

If i enter this url `hostname/xxxx` means it directly go to my folder but i want it go to my code controller

`Without Login the images should not get viewed`.

Also Without login means the URL should get redirected.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Zabavsky: To view a images in folder, should get login, without login the images should not visible.Is there any idea to login to view a images??

Comment: That's a good plan. Good luck! If you come across some difficulties don't hesite to ask them here.

Comment: If anyone have idea, Please suggest me...

Comment: The easy way, you should set the access rights to the folder, in IIS. You can also do it in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

> Without Login the images should not get viewed.

I assume you are using **form authentication**. Otherwise, this method won't work.

1. Create web.config file inside xxxx folder
2. Place the following [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inside the web.config file

It basically restricts anonymous users accessing the files inside xxxx folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note: you should not use this approach for restricting Controller in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: :Now I can access that content folder if i give the that file name means it always come to my controller it didn't go to the folder content